# Does running clasp scripts require a paid setup for the Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I am to run Google Apps scripts from the command line with clasp.

I had a problem, and at https://github.com/google/clasp/issues/506 I was instructed to

> Inside browser Click Resources -> Cloud Platform Project -> Project and click on the link to Google Cloud Console.
> Go to API Library and enable Apps Script API.

This refers to the Google Cloud Platform. I tried to use it but after some screens it wanted me to give payment credentials.

Should I pay to use clasp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should enable billing and in some case you must enable billing.

The clear distinction between Google services and Google Cloud services is going away. Today, most service require a Google Cloud account be setup with billing enabled. Tomorrow, probably all will require this.

For services which have large free quotas, billing is used to verify who you are and to prevent abuse.